# GEE: Select random sample on known-NDVI-range for supervised classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, sampling

I intend to get random samples for training the supervised classification in Google earth engine.
The code here, for example, I calculate NDVI and mask out NDVI < 0.65 (i.e. NDVI >= 0.65 is vegetation). Then, I convert the regions to the vector region. And, I take random samples on the vector region.
For example, The number of samples I would like to get is 200. But, It returns more than 200.
The reason here, I guess due to vector layer contains many polygons. 
So, any solution for this problem?

```
// region roi
var roi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[100.51605775066919, 13.73170620808265],
          [100.51605775066919, 13.620954851424335],
          [100.72239472576685, 13.620954851424335],
          [100.72239472576685, 13.73170620808265]]], null, false);

// Image collection       
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
    var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
          .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
          .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
    var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image
  .select("B[1-5]*")
  .updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};


var collection1 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2003-01-01', '2003-12-31');

var l7 = collection1
    .map(cloudMaskL457)
    .median()
    .clip(roi);

// NDVI calculation
//var tool = require('users/Plant_phenology/functions:func_general');
//var ndvi = tool.diff_index(l7, 'B4', 'B3', "ndvi");
var ndvi = l7.expression(
    ' ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED))', {
      'NIR': l7.select('B4'),
      'RED': l7.select('B3'),
}).rename('ndvi');


// Mask out NDVI < 0.65
var vi = ndvi.updateMask(ndvi.gte(0.65));
var mask = vi.gte(0.65);
var vi = mask.multiply(0).add(1);
Map.addLayer(vi, {min: 0.5, max: 1}, "vege");



// Convert to vector
var vege = vi.reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
  geometry: roi, 
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e8
});


// get random samples
var getSamples = function(image, samplesFcs, samplesPoints, nsamples, label){
  var samplesCollection = ee.List(samplesFcs).iterate(
    function(sample,totalSample){
        return ee.FeatureCollection(totalSample).merge(sample);
      }
    ,ee.FeatureCollection([]));

    samplesCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(samplesCollection);
    return samplesCollection;

    var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(samplesCollection, nSamples, 1989);

      samplesPoints.forEach(function(points) {
        randomPoints = randomPoints.merge(points);
      });c

     return randomPoints;
};     

var class4 = [vege];
var class4Points = [];
var nsamples = 200;

var test = getSamples(vi, class4, class4Points, nsamples);
print(test.size(),'samples Vegetation');
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot execute this code, it's using `users/Plant_phenology/functions:func_general`, which I don't have access to. Just looking at it, you have a very suspicious return statement, `return samplesCollection`,  in `getSamples()`, preventing you from doing any sampling at all.